# Using macro results in incorrect output when used as part of a larger math expression - why does this happen?

Tags: c, macros

This is a normal C routine program which i found out in some question bank. It is shown below:

```
#define CUBE(p) p*p*p

main()
{
    int k;
    k = 27 / CUBE(3);
    printf("%d", k);
}
```

As per my understanding and knowledge the value of K should be 1 as CUBE(3) would be replaced by 3*3*3 during preprocessing and after the subsequent compilation it would be giving the value of 1, but instead it has shown the value of 81 which has made me curious to know how it happened.

Can anyone please justify the answer of 81 to this question above.

Comment: Just replace `CUBE(3)` in your `k=...` line by `3*3*3` and see what you get your expression to be.

Comment: What language is it that makes "doubts" seem like a synonym for "problem" or "question"?

Comment: @Ether: As an Indian, I can definitely say that that's us.  I learned the hard way myself! Once my professor said to me: "Do you have a doubt about the question, or a question about the question?" I hope you don't doubt me when I say that. :-)

Comment: When you work with preprocessor problem like that use the preprocessor output to see where the problem is located (gcc -E file.c)

Comment: This is why it is recommended to use functions instead of macros.  On most modern compilers, the speed is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocessors should be parenthesized properly.  Replace it with

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
```

and see.

Comment: And beware, even this is broken for CUBE(++i) or CUBE(f(x))

Answer (score 15):

The preprocessor merely substitutes

```
CUBE(3)
```

with

```
3*3*3
```

So you end up with:

```
k=27/3*3*3
```

Which, evaluated left-to-right with operator precedence, is in fact 81.

If you add parenthesees around the macro, you should find the results are correct:

```
#define CUBE(p) (p*p*p)
```

It would be even better to surround each instance of `p` with parenthesees as well, as in:

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
```

Which will allow you to pass expressions to the macro correctly (for example, `1 + 2`).

Comment: Or, better, `#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))`

Comment: I'd actually make it:
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
But even that's bad, if p is a function call. It may inadvertently get called 3 times.

Comment: wow...Thats jst the game of operator precedence.Thanks James and Alok.

Comment: That's why the convention is to use UPPERCASE for macros - so that you realise that they may evaluate their arguments more than once.

Answer (score 4):

**Because of operator precedence `27/3*3*3 = 81`**

You could use instead:

```
inline int cube(int p) { return p*p*p; }
```

Answer (score 2):

C macros do textual substitution (i.e. it's equivalent to copying and pasting code).  So your code goes from:

```
k=27/CUBE(3);
```

to

```
k=27/3*3*3;
```

Division and multiplication have the same precedence and have left-to-right associativity, so this is parsed as:

```
k=((27/3)*3)*3;
```

which is 9 * 3 * 3 = 81.

This is why C macros should always be defined with liberal use of parentheses:

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p) * (p) * (p))
```

For more information, see http://c-faq.com/cpp/safemacros.html from the comp.lang.c FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

Your macro is not protected. Try

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
```

The current macro was expanded to

```
k=27/3*3*3
```

which is ((27/3)*3)*3

Answer (score 1):

Because macros are a textual substitution, that works out to:

```
k = 27 / 3 * 3 * 3;
```

Since multiplication and division happen left to right, that works out to:

```
k = ((27 / 3) * 3) * 3;
```

So, you want to change that in two ways:

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
```

The outer parentheses cause the multiplications to be done before any other operations.

The parentheses around the individual p's are for the case where you do:

```
CUBE(1 + 2);
```

Without those inner parentheses, operator precedence will trip you up.

Answer (score 0):

```
     #define CUBE(p) p*p*p
     main()
     {
        int k;
        k=27/CUBE(3);
        printf("%d",k);

     }
```

> As per my understanding and knowledge the value of K should be 1 as CUBE(3) would be replaced by 3*3*3 during preprocessing

YES

> and after the subsequent compilation it would be giving the value of 1,but instead it has shown the value of 81 which has made me curious to know how it happenned.

NO,

```
k= 27/3*3*3 

 =(((27/3)*3)*3) (The precedence of `*` and `/` are same but the associativity is from left to right)
 =((9*3)*3) =81
```

Replace `#define CUBE(p) p*p*p` with `#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))`

Answer (score 0):

```
k=27/CUBE(3);  =>   k=27/3 * 3 * 3;
```

Do you see it? CUBE should be defined like this instead:

```
#define CUBE(p) ((p)*(p)*(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do macros, you have to be careful about how you place parentheses. In this case, you don't have any, so the expression becomes 27/3*3*3, which by the precedence rules of / and * becomes (27/3)*3*3.

Answer (score 0):

27/3*3*3 = 9*3*3 = 81 ?

Answer (score 0):

Both / and * operators have the same precedence. To execure 3*3*3 first, you shoudl enclose them in parenthesis.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUBE(p) p*p*p

int
main ()
{
  int k;
  k=27/(CUBE(3));
  printf("%d",k);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its the way in which the associativity and precedence of operators is implemented.
when the expression is expanded it becomes 
**27/3*3*3 and not 27/(3*3*3)**
now, division and multiplication both have the same precedence in C but the associativity is left to right for both.
so it can be shown as :
(27/3)*3*3 which in turn equals (9*3)*3 = 81
also, if u remember the old arithmetic rule of **BODMAS(Bracket Off Division Multiplication Addition Subtraction)**, this is the order of precedence, then we do division first and then multiplication. 
so again we get answer as 81 for 27/3*3*3.

Answer (score 0):

Hi answer for this is:81
Explanation:
In step k=27/cube(3)
cube(3) is replaced by 3*3*3 by preprocessor.then above statement becomes as k=27/3*3*3
in that 27/3 expression is evaluated by c compiler(operator precedence)
the result is(27/3) :9
the statement k=27/3*3*3 becomes as k=9*3*3;
the result for above statement is 81: