# Why does using the bit mask 0x30000 give a different result than using 0x3 << 16?

Tags: c

Today I wrote a program but something is wrong with it, so I made this test program. Well, `0x30000` is equal to `0x3 << 16`, isn't it?

In this program, it shows that `0x30000` is equal to `0x3 << 16` in the beginning, but finally, this program give me totally different result!, I don't why, this result is so strange!

The output is:

```
MASK1
0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000
MASK2
0000 0000 0000 0011 0000 0000 0000 0000
equal!!!!!
Before 1
0000 0000 0001 0010 1101 0110 1000 0111
After 1
0000 0000 0001 0000 1101 0110 1000 0111
Before 2
0000 0000 0001 0010 1101 0110 1000 0111
After 2
0000 0000 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Why are the outputs after `MASK1` and `MASK2` totally different?
`MASK1` did the right thing, but something seems to go wrong with `MASK2`. Why do I get these results?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MASK1 0x30000
#define MASK2 0x3 << 16

void show_binary(unsigned long n);

void change_alignment(unsigned long *s);
void eatline(void);
int main(void)
{
    unsigned long   num;
    puts("MASK1");
    show_binary(MASK1);
    puts("MASK2");
    show_binary(MASK2);
    num = 1234567;

    if(MASK1 == MASK2)
        puts("equal!!!!!");
    puts("Before 1");
    show_binary(num);
    num &= ~MASK1;
    puts("After 1");
    show_binary(num);

    num = 1234567;
    puts("Before 2");

    show_binary(num);
    num &= ~MASK2;
    puts("After 2");
    show_binary(num);

    return 0;
}

void show_binary(unsigned long n)
{
    unsigned long   mask = 1;
    int     size = sizeof(unsigned long) * 8;
    char        bin[size + 1];
    int         index = 0;

    bin[size] = '\0';

    while(size > 0)
    {
        if((mask & n) == mask)
            bin[size - 1] = '1';
        else
            bin[size - 1] = '0';

        mask <<= 1;
        size--;
    }

    while(bin[index])
    {
        putchar(bin[index]);
        if(++index % 4 == 0 && bin[index])
            putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}

void eatline(void)
{
    while(getchar() != '\n')
        continue;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preprocessing doubts in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115095/preprocessing-doubts-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're simply hit by the fact that macros are text substitutions, and that [C's precendence rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) are what they are.

This:

```
num &= ~MASK2;
```

will be seen by the compiler as:

```
num &= ~0x3 << 16;
```

Which is not what you mean (since `~` binds tigher than the shift, it's evaluated as `(~3) << 16`). You must add parenthesis to the macro:

```
#define MASK2 (0x3 << 16)
```

One should *never* define a macro as an expression without enclosing it in parenthesis, since you don't know how the macro will be used.

Answer (score 1):

Since `~` has a higher precedence than `<<`, the expression

```
~0x3<<16
```

which is the result of evaluating the macro

```
~MASK2
```

Evaluates to:

```
(~0x3)<<16
```

And not to:

```
~(0x3<<16)
```

So while the following is true (when performing the macro replacement manually):

```
0x30000 == 0x3<<16
```

Since `==` as less precedence than `<<`, the following is not:

```
~0x30000 == ~0x3<<16 // FALSE -> ~0x3<<16 = (~0x3)<<16
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a parenthesis: try

```
#define MASK2 (0x3 << 16)
```